# Make next EditText appear on screen when action next clicked

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-inputtype

I have several EditTexts on my screen and they are all built in the following way.

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            app:fontFamily="@font/karla"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapCharacters"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:textColor="#5C7264"
            />
```

Code:

```
private void addItemsToLinearLayout(int numItems) {

 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

     for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {

         View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_linearlayout, null);        

         linearlayoutPlayersNames.addView(childView);            

         ImageView deleteRowIcon = childView.findViewById(R.id.deleteRowIcon);     
         deleteRowIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

         TextView myTV = childView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);          
         myTV.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.player), linearlayoutPlayersNames.indexOfChild(childView) + 1));         


         EditText editText = childView.findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText);
         editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
         editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);

    }
}
```

When I click the next button of the soft keyboard it moves to the next EditText as expected, BUT ONLY if the next EditText is visible on screen. When the next EditText is not visible on screen the action next has no effect and, on top of that, it changes the next action button to a carriage return action button as shown in this video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hzm2.jpg

What I intend to do is to click the next button and move the visibility to the next EditText.

**UPDATE**: some of you have told me to do this using `android:nextFocusDown` or programmatically with `editText.setNextFocusForwardId(editTextSecond.getId());` but I can't because I use a loop to create the `EditText`s as shown now in the code.

Comment: have you tried in your xml android:imeOptions="actionNext" ?

Comment: @AntonisRadz As you can see, it is set programmatically. The misbehavior comes into place when the next EditText is not visible on screen.

Comment: Is there no other solution @AbidKhan ?  I generate the EditTexts programmatically depending on the amount of players that want to play so it isn't easy for me to do this.

Comment: check using the `edittext.setSingleLine(true);` or `edittext.setMaxLines(1);`

Comment: Check it in my answer then.

Comment: set editText.setId(1000+i); editText.setNextFocusForwardId(editText.getId()+1);  I hope, it may helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
  EditText editText2 = childView.findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText);
  EditText editText = childView.findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText);
  editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        editText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        editText2.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
        editText2.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
              return handled;
             }
        }
    });

  editText2.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
               // do same for others to    
            return handled;  
             }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to remove `textMultiLine` from `android:inputType` then it will work with both the cases next EditText is visible and not visible.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        app:fontFamily="@font/karla"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:textColor="#5C7264"
        />
```

Comment: I want to use textMultiLine... And even doing so it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are doing it programmatically than in instead in xml using

```
android:nextFocusDown="@id/textInputEditTextSecond"
```

You can use it programmatically like this

```
editText.setNextFocusForwardId(editTextSecond.getId());
```

and add `editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);` for all EditText

Inside for loop setId of each EditText and then set nextForward as below

```
private void addItemsToLinearLayout(int numItems) {

 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

     for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {

         View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_linearlayout, null);        

         linearlayoutPlayersNames.addView(childView);            

         ImageView deleteRowIcon = childView.findViewById(R.id.deleteRowIcon);     
         deleteRowIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

         TextView myTV = childView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);          
         myTV.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.player), linearlayoutPlayersNames.indexOfChild(childView) + 1));         


         EditText editText = childView.findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText);
         editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
         editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);

         // setId of each EditText and then set nextForward as
         editText.setId(i);
         editText.setNextFocusForwardId(i+1);

    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but my case is a bit more complicated as my update of the question shows.

Comment: Thank you once again, but it doesn't work in my case either... I guess for someone else it may be helpful but not for me. I have a more complex layout where, once the user has chosen the amount of players he can also remove and add more so after removing players and adding new ones these new players ids wouldn't be sequential and thus the behaviour of .setNextFocusForwardId would be unexpected.